# Is there a way to gather data of Optical Module Status and the CPU Utilization through SNMP protocol?

Tags: cisco, switch, network, snmp

When using the snmpwalk command to query a **Cisco SF302-08PP** switch with the -c public community string, am not able to find data related to Optical Module Status and CPU Utilization. I am trying to collect the data of a switch through snmp protocol using the following command:

`snmpwalk -v2c -c public IP_ADDRESS_CONNECTED_SWITCH`

Is there a recommended solution or alternative approach to successfully retrieve data on Optical Module Status and CPU Utilization through SNMP for this particular switch model?

Comment: snmpwalk usually won't dive into the enterprises tree, and that's where these would logically exist. You'll have to dig through mib definitions to find if it's even supported.

Comment: @Ricky Could you provide more details on how I can effectively explore the enterprises tree using SNMP to gather data on Optical Module Status and CPU Utilization? Any guidance on which specific MIBs or OIDs I should be looking for would be incredibly helpful.
I'm relatively new to SNMP and any additional information or examples you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add the word "enterprises" to your command. But without the mibs, those numbers won't mean anything.